# Overriding a:hover text-decoration in a different class

Tags: css, class, overriding

I have all links on my site underlined when hovered using the following css:

```
a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

How can I make a class which will override this?

```
.footer {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second selector is less accurate than the first one, therefore it's the first one that is applied.

Plus, you shouldn't target such a wide selector (.footer) in order to only style your links. What you should do is:

.footer a:hover{ text-decoration: none; }

(As I assume that default a state doesn't have a text-decoration: underline;)

Answer (score 0):

This code seemed to fix it although it wasn't working earlier:
    a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    } 
    .footer a{
    text-decoration:none;
    }